# How to run a java program using ProcessBuilder in high priority?

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, processbuilder

I am using a batch file to invoke a GUI.  This GUI has a button (B1) that on click invokes a copy of itself.  Now I want to increase the priority of the GUI whether it's run from the batch or button B1.

With batch, I am able to increase it's priority but not with B1.

The following code executes on click of button B1: (I am  using cmd to increase the priority; I don't know if there is any other way)

```
final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", 
  " /C", 
  " start /high", 
  path,
  "-DTESTKERNEL_PROPERTIES=" + tempFile.getCanonicalPath(),
  "-Djava.util.logging.config.file=" + loggingFile,
  "-Djava.library.path=" + libraryPath,
  "-cp",
  classpath,
  "com.abc.cde.gui.typetwo.GuiTypeTwo");
processBuilder.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
```

`DTESTKERNEL_PROPERTIES` is a properties file and is required for the execution of code.

This is the output as list:

```
cmd, 
/C, 
start, 
/high, 
D:\jdk\jre\bin\javaw, 
-DTESTKERNEL_PROPERTIES=C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\testkernel2667928753863437728.properties, 
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=../config/logging.properties, 
-Djava.library.path=D:\TestKernalMain\lib, 
-cp, 
D:\Workspace\TestKernalMain\bin;
D:\TestKernalMain\lib\bundled\bsh-2.0b5.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\lib\bundled\commons-cli-1.2.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\lib\bundled\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\lib\bundled\commons-configuration-1.8.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\lib\bundled\commons-io-2.0.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\lib\bundled\commons-lang-2.5.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\lib\bundled\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\lib\bundled\commons-net-2.2.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\lib\bundled\commons-vfs2-2.0.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\lib\bundled\eventbus-1.4.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\lib\bundled\javasimon-core-2.3.0.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\lib\bundled\javasimon-jmx-2.3.0.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\lib\bundled\jpcsc.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-antlr.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-apache-bcel.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-apache-bsf.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-apache-log4j.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-apache-oro.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-apache-regexp.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-apache-resolver.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-apache-xalan2.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-commons-logging.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-commons-net.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-contrib.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-jai.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-javamail.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-jdepend.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-jmf.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-jsch.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-junit.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-junit4.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-launcher.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-netrexx.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-swing.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant-testutil.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\ant\ant.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\cardreader\javactapi.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\iText\iText-2.1.7.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\iText\iText-rtf-2.1.7.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\jdiff\antjdiff.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\jdiff\jdiff.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\jdiff\xerces.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tools\JUnit\junit.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tests\lib\cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tests\lib\easymock-3.0.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tests\lib\jetm-1.2.3.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tests\lib\jetm-optional-1.2.3.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\tests\lib\obj-1.2.jar;
D:\Workspace\GUITypeTwo\bin;
D:\TestKernalMain\lib\TestKernel.jar;
D:\GUITypeTwo\lib\external\docking-frames-core.jar;
D:\GUITypeTwo\lib\external\docking-frames-common.jar;
D:\GUITypeTwo\lib\external\glasslib.jar;
D:\GUITypeTwo\lib\external\docking-frames-ext-glass.jar;
D:\GUITypeTwo\lib\external\h2-1.3.167.jar;
D:\GUITypeTwo\lib\external\mydoggy-api.jar;
D:\GUITypeTwo\lib\external\mydoggy-plaf.jar;
D:\GUITypeTwo\lib\external\mydoggy-res.jar;
D:\GUITypeTwo\lib\external\swingx-core-1.6.2.jar;
D:\GUITypeTwo\lib\external\TableLayout.jar;
D:\GUITypeTwo\lib\external\ValidationAPI.jar;
D:\GUITypeTwo\tools\MPlus.jar;
D:\GUITypeTwo\tools\JUnit\junit-4.9.jar;
D:\TestKernalMain\config, 
com.gui.typetwo.GuiTypeTwo
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spaces before `/C` and `start` and split `"start /high"` into two separate parameters:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "start", "/high", ...)
```

Comment: It says "windows can not find -DTESTKERNEL_PROPERTIES=" i cross checked and found that the file is present at the desired location

Comment: What is the value of `path`? Can you first put all process arguments in a list, print it, post the output in your original question and then invoke `new ProcessBuilder(list)`? There must be some typo or other minor issue there.

Comment: The arguments have proper values, i tried to use the list instead. Gives the same result. "Windows cannot find......."

Comment: Please help anyone. Am really stuck here!

Comment: Well, I asked you some questions that you didn't answer (you only said that "the arguments have proper values" - if they did, there wouldn't be a problem), so without more insight there's not much that can be done. Please put all arguments in a list and post the `toString()` of that list here.

Comment: On copy pasting the output to cmd, it says invalid switch "/high"

Comment: Which Windows version? I'm running Win 8.1 and when I run `cmd /C start /high echo Hello` it doesn't show any error, just spawns a new window and displays "Hello". Try to make it work in the console first.

Comment: windows 7 professional, service pack 1. I've added the list you asked in the description.

Comment: Windows is showing wierd behaviour as in when I try to run a program (say notepad) in high priority, sometimes it sets the priority(when i tried to open cmd in high priority) the other times it doesn't (tried notepad++)

Comment: try cmd /C start /high notepad++ and check the priority.

Comment: Adam Michalik ?? can you help?

Comment: Works fine by me - notepad starts with "high" prio

Comment: Could you please try with Notepad++ ??